# WordPress REST API custom endpoint not allowing multiple parameters

Tags: rest-api, parameter

I've made a custom endpoint for my REST API:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
 register_rest_route( 'foo/v1', '/bar/', array(
   'methods' => 'GET',
   'callback' => 'foo_callback',
 ) );
} );
```

I normally have a WP query as my callback, but to simplify things let's pretend I'm just asking for certain parameters to be returned to me:

```
function foo_callback(){
    $string = "";  
    if($_REQUEST['paged']){
       $string .= $_REQUEST['paged'];
    }
    if($_REQUEST['posts_per_page']){
       $string .= $_REQUEST['posts_per_page']; 
    }

    return $string; 
}
```

I'm also locking down my API so only logged-in users can access it, requiring an Application Password.

```
add_filter( 'rest_authentication_errors', function( $result ) {
    if ( ! empty( $result ) ) {
        return $result;
    }
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'rest_not_logged_in', 'You're not logged in bozo.', array( 'status' => 401 ) );
    }
    return $result;
});
```

This API request with a single parameter works:

```
curl -X GET https://example.com/wp-json/foo/v1/bar?posts_per_page=1 -H "Authorization: Basic xxxxx"
```

This API request with a different parameter works:

```
curl -X GET https://example.com/wp-json/foo/v1/bar?paged=2 -H "Authorization: Basic xxxxx"
```

But this API request combining both parameters does not work:

```
curl -X GET https://example.com/wp-json/foo/v1/bar?posts_per_page=1&paged=2 -H "Authorization: Basic xxxxx"
```

In fact, it tells me "You're not logged in, bozo". Multiple parameters are somehow triggering my  !is_user_logged_in() rule (although it throws up a generic error even if I remove that clause).

What am I doing wrong, and what's the correct way to allow multiple parameters in my endpoint?

Comment: Argh - ignore me. It was a simple matter of needing quotation marks in my cURL around the URL. :/

Comment: can you post that as an answer rather than a comment?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer to a long question:

I needed quotation marks round the URL.

```
curl -X GET "https://example.com/wp-json/foo/v1/bar?posts_per_page=1&paged=2" -H "Authorization: Basic xxxxx"
```